# Is the conformal Killing factor always an eigenvalue of the Laplacian?

Tags: differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, curvature, laplacian, conformal-geometry

Suppose $(M, g)$ is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold and $\xi_{\mu}$ is a conformal Killing field, i.e.
$$
  \nabla_{\nu} \xi_{\mu} + \nabla_{\mu} \xi_{\nu} = \kappa g_{\mu \nu}
$$
for some smooth function $\kappa$.
\begin{align*}
(\text{tr} g-2)\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu \kappa +
  g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^\alpha\nabla_\alpha\kappa&=
                                              g^{\alpha\beta}\left(g_{\mu\nu}\nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta+g_{\alpha\beta}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu-g_{\alpha\mu}\nabla_\beta\nabla_\nu-g_{\beta\nu}\nabla_\mu\nabla_\alpha\right)\kappa 
  \\
  &= g^{\alpha\beta}\left[ \nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta(\nabla_{\mu} \xi_{\nu} + \nabla_{\nu}
    \xi_{\mu})+\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu(\nabla_{\alpha} \xi_{\beta} + \nabla_{\beta}
    \xi_{\alpha}) \right. 
  \\
  &\left. \quad \quad \ -\nabla_\beta\nabla_\nu(\nabla_{\mu} \xi_{\alpha} + \nabla_{\alpha}
    \xi_{\mu})-\nabla_\mu\nabla_\alpha(\nabla_{\beta} \xi_{\nu} + \nabla_{\nu}
    \xi_{\beta}) \right] 
  \\
  &= g ^{\alpha \beta} \left[ (\nabla _{\alpha \beta \mu} ^3 - \nabla_{\mu \alpha \beta} ^3)\xi_{\nu} +
    (\nabla_{\alpha \beta \nu} ^3 - \nabla_{\beta \nu \alpha} ^3)\xi_{\mu} \right. 
  \\
  &\left. \quad \quad \quad \ (\nabla_{\mu \nu \beta} ^3 - \nabla_{\beta \nu \mu} ^3)\xi_{\alpha} + (\nabla_{\mu \nu \alpha} ^3 -
    \nabla_{\mu \alpha \nu} ^3)\xi_{\beta}\right] \tag{*}
\end{align*}
where $\nabla_{\alpha \beta \mu} ^3 = \nabla_{\alpha} \nabla_{\beta} \nabla_{\mu}$. When the Riemann curvature
tensor vanishes, the covariant derivatives commute and we obtain:
$$
  (\text{tr} g -2) \nabla_{\mu} \nabla_{\nu} \kappa + g_{\mu \nu }\Delta_g \kappa = 0.
$$
Otherwise, I do not know how to get rid of the dependence on $\xi$ on the right hand side. I have been toying
around with the Riemann tensor but I do not get the necessary cancellations. Because there are four terms, I
believe that each term must be independent of $\xi$, since otherwise, the only other way I see any
cancellations occurring is via Bianchi identities, which have only 3 terms. This is of course just a heuristic
but even then, I have not managed to simplify the equation enough to make it depend only on $\kappa$. Is there
a way to make the the RHS of $(*)$ independent of $\xi$?